# Bootstrap 4 sidebar collapse not working - Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, angular6

i want to collapse and reopen the sidebar when i click on a button , i tried to add function that can do what i want but it didn't worked with me.

Note: I want to collapse the sidebar without using jquery or javascript

This what i am working on :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n4x1br?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsidebar%2Fsidebar.component.html

Answer (score 1):

Your `ngClass` attribute adds a class called `show`, but the class you want is actually called `active`.

```
<nav id="sidebar" [ngClass]="{ 'active': navbarOpen }">
```

**[Here is a fork of the StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fwrfzb?file=src/app/sidebar/sidebar.component.html)**

Comment: yes sorry , you are correct , but there is another thing that  when i close the sidebar i should the second button icon should show up 

This is the button 
 <button class="btn btn-dark d-inline-block d-lg-none ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <i class="fas fa-align-justify"></i>
          </button>

Comment: @JamesFallon Just add `*ngIf="!navbarOpen"` onto the button then. At the moment the icon isn't showing because you've not added fontawesome

Comment: no i installed font awesome package and i don't think this is the problem because i tried to add new icon and worked

Comment: Make sure that you're using the correct class. If you're using v4.7 of fontawesome, it should be `fa fa-align-justify` not `fas fa-align-justify`, but it seems to work in the StackBlitz

Answer (score 0):

create a boolean collapsed = true and the variable is become a false when you click in your button and become a true when you click a button again and yout style html(css) is change according to your varibale if true make this css if false make this css
Good Luck

this is in your html

```
<div class="sidenav" [ngClass]="screen.collapsed ? 'sidenav-collapsed': ''">
```

this is your function in your ts file

```
togglecollapse(): void{ 
this.screen.collapsed = !this.screen.collapsed;
```

}

callung your function when your click your button make change in your varible
and the change make another change in your css